# Female lead got reincarnated into her childhood

Tags: story-identification, manga

There’s a manga that I’m trying to find. The female was sent back to her childhood, the story starts with her mom waking her up from her nightmare or something. In that chapter, you could see that she was wearing shabby clothes.

Her father's family doesn’t treat her family properly. She came up with a plan to make her father's parents share the inheritance with them. She knew the family wouldn’t do it fairly so she called a village elder who is most trusted to be the witness for the deal. Once the deal was over she and her family left the house for a home close to the elder.

From what I remember the female had a cheat where she could stores object and animal inside. She can also go inside the item. Her dad, who was a hunter, was able to catch a boar with a trap that they dug; the boar fell in and died on the spikes.

With her friend, she caught fish and sell in the marketplace, they made a business out of it. They also build a pond to keep the fish fresh to sell. I also remembered there was a boy and her sister who was not welcome in their family, I believe their dad or grandfather sent them there to live there. In one of the chapters, someone from their family came back to bring them home but he refuses to go.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it colour or black-and-white?

Comment: Do you remember anything about her first life? Presumably she died; do you remember how, or what kind of life she lived before that? It can be hard to tell, but do you have any idea if this was a manga aimed at men (i.e. shonen or seinen) or women (shoujo or josei)?